# How to add markups to 2D model like 2D-dwg/pdf/dxf in Autodesk Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I would like to show 2D-dwg/pdf/dxf in Autodesk Viewer and add on them markups such as comments, triangles, arrows and so on.
How can you achieve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend looking into building your own Markup experience like we specify on this blog - https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/implementing-custom-markups